# Lower bounds on random process

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ be i.i.d. random signs, $\mathbf{u}_1,...,\mathbf{u}_n$ i.i.d. uniform random vectors on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, assuming $d$ even, and $\mathbf{v}_1,...,\mathbf{v}_n$ be their half-truncations, that is $\mathbf{v}_i[j] = \mathbf{u}_i[j]$ for all $j \in \left \{1,...,d/2\right\}$, else $\mathbf{v}_i[j] = 0$, where $\mathbf{v}_i[j]$ denotes the $j$-th entry of $\mathbf{v}_i$. We assume that the $\epsilon_i$'s are independent from the $\mathbf{u}_i$'s. 
I am looking for nontrivial lower bounds on the following quantity.
$$\mathbb{E}\left |\sum_{i = 1}^n \epsilon_i \| \mathbf{v}_i\|^2_2 \right |$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon\newcommand\v{\mathbf v}$Conditioning on the $\ep_i$'s and using Jensen's and [Szarek's](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-smv58i1p13bwm) inequalities, we have
$$E\Big|\sum_1^n\ep_i\|\v_i\|_2^2\Big|
\ge E\Big|\sum_1^n\ep_ic_i\Big|\ge\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\sum_1^nc_i^2},$$
where
$$c_i:=E\|\v_i\|_2^2=1/2,$$
by symmetry. So,
$$E\Big|\sum_1^n\ep_i\|\v_i\|_2^2\Big|
\ge \frac{\sqrt n}2.$$

---

This lower bound is of course sharp, up a universal constant factor, because
$$E\Big|\sum_1^n\ep_i\|\v_i\|_2^2\Big|
\le\sqrt{E\Big(\sum_1^n\ep_i\|\v_i\|_2^2\Big)^2}
=\sqrt{\sum_1^n E\|\v_i\|_2^4}
= \sqrt{n E\|\v_1\|_2^4}
\le\sqrt n.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is indeed what I was looking for!